# Solution of the autonomous D.E. : $yy''-{(y')}^2={y^2}y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the O.D.E. $yy''-{(y')}^2={y^2}y'$ We take the substitution $y'=z$ , $y''=z \frac{dz} {dy}$ ,for $yz\neq 0$ .Then $yz\frac{dz} {dy}-z^2=y^2z \implies \frac{y\frac{dz}{dy}-z} {y^2}=1 \implies z=y^2+c_1y$ ,for some constant $c_1$

That is if we observe that in the second implication we have the derivative of a fraction.If we didn't see that and went "by the book" saying that this is a first order linear D.E. we would have as solution the following:

$z(x)=exp(-\int-\frac{1}{y}dy)(c_1+\int y\cdot exp(\int-\frac{1}{y}dy)dy) \implies y'=y^2+c_1|y|$

Why does that happen? Why if we use the second way we have absolute value of y and what information am I missing?

Comment: You're wright,I fixed it.

Comment: With that correction I would expect that your equation reads $yy''-y'^2=y^2y'$. Then indeed $\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=y'\implies y'=cy+y^2$.

Comment: Oh God,I'm terribly sorry,one moment.

Answer (score 1):

The separation formula used for the integration factor is only valid for regions where $y\ne 0$. The given equation is also singular on that line, so that this division of the domain is not artificial.

Thus in joining the regions after the first integration you have the choice of the sign for both regions separately. Note that in each region the sign is just another constant factor additional to $c_1$, so you can write $y'=y^2+c_1y$ with the sign joined with the constant. As the equation demands $y=0\implies y'=0\implies y''=0$ independent of $c_1$, solutions for different $c_1$ on both sides of the divide can be joined as twice continuously differentiable functions. However, no IVP can have an initial condition $y=0$ with $y'\ne 0$.